# Get value from Dictionary, Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I have a problem with getting one specific value from dictionary. Let's say that it looks like that

```
currency = {'bat (Tajlandia)': 0.1062},{'dolar amerykański': 3.3375},{'dolar australijski': 2.6997},{'dolar Hongkongu': 0.4268},{'dolar kanadyjski': 2.7015},{'dolar nowozelandzki': 2.4441},{'dolar singapurski': 2.5486},{'euro': 4.1423},{'forint (Węgry)': 0.013388},{'frank szwajcarski': 3.5625}
```

and I would like to get that kind of output:

```
print(dictionary['euro'])

4.1423
```

Of course I see that currency has a lot of dictionary and I tried to use a FOR loop but I could get a lot of "none" and I need to get only one result.

Comment: What you've posted is a tuple of dictionaries, not a dictionary, and would not be something you got from JSON. Please give an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this:

```
print(currency['euro'])
```

It should print:

```
4.1423
```

Your currency OTOH needs to be like this (you were missing `{` and `}` and some dictionary inside dictionary related stuff):

```
currency = {
   'bat (Tajlandia)': 0.1062,
   'dolar amerykański': 3.3375,
   'dolar australijski': 2.6997,
   ...
   'euro': 4.1423,
   'forint (Węgry)': 0.013388,
   'frank szwajcarski': 3.5625
}
```

Comment: I need that looks like currency but I can' get this. Do you know how I could convert my "currency" into your ? It would solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert your `currency` tuple of dictionaries into your required `dictionary`, you could do the following:

```
currency = {'bat (Tajlandia)': 0.1062},{'dolar amerykański': 3.3375},{'dolar australijski': 2.6997},{'dolar Hongkongu': 0.4268},{'dolar kanadyjski': 2.7015},{'dolar nowozelandzki': 2.4441},{'dolar singapurski': 2.5486},{'euro': 4.1423},{'forint (Węgry)': 0.013388},{'frank szwajcarski': 3.5625}            
dictionary = {k:v for d in currency for k, v in d.items()}
print(dictionary['euro'])
```

This would display:

```
4.1423
```

Answer (score -1):

## Only for this structure:

```py
#type(currency) # tuple
#type(currency[0]) # dict
for item in currency:
    if 'euro' in item.keys():
        # print(item) # {'euro': 4.1423}
        print(item['euro']) # 4.123
```